# Help with boot screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, graphics

I want to have a different boot screen when I start my computer. Right now it just is a black screen saying starting this and starting that, etc. I want to have a graphic design like the Ubuntu logo spinning in the example Ubuntu files.

Comment: Sorry, but its not that easy, even if it is possible for your system. 
In short, what your computer behaves like, before starting any operating system, is all controlled by what is called as the ROM in the motherboard, and the BIOS. Yes, you can ask any computer dealer, if it is possible to upgrade BIOS of your system. That might (or might not) make the boot screen more colorful.
But you definitely won't get any animation filled BOOT screen, as far as my knowledge takes me.

Answer (score 1):

I have my self been struggling with this particular issue last night! (I just love geeky text that im not able to read cause it loads so damn fast)

Anyways, my conclusion was: to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` into: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` and then afterwards removing the hash tag in `#GRUB_TERMINAL=Console` so the line will look like this: `GRUB_TERMINAL=Console`.

So to sum up, remove quiet and splash, and afterwards activate the `GRUB_Terminal=console` line.

Good luck, have fun.

Comment: Oh my bad, my guide is to the opposite :)